# Get Access denied users list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, compliance-center

In order to accomplish a requirement of the internal audit department, I need to obtain the list of denied access to a sharepoint online site. Could I get it using power shell?

I can´t find this option in Security&Compliance site or Exchange Admin Site. We are using O365 and SharePoint Online classic team sites.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c#PickTab=Activities) , if your Auditing logging are configured right, you should be able to filter your audits about **Denied access request** which covers access request to a site, folder, or document was denied.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://protection.office.com.

Sign in to Office 365 using your work or school account.

In the left pane of the Security & Compliance Center, click Search & investigation, and then click Audit log search.

The Audit log search page is displayed.

Under Activities, click Denied access request to search for Access denied users list:
[image]

Reference:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-sharing-auditing-in-the-Office-365-audit-log-50bbf89f-7870-4c2a-ae14-42635e0cfc01